# How to get the list of changelist already integrated?

Tags: version-control, perforce

There is `interchanges` command in perforce which lists changelists between two branches that have not been integrated with the convenience of a `branchspec`.

Is there something that shows the changelists that have been integrated something like the reverse of `interchanges` and also works with a `branchspec`?

More interested in terminal perforce rather than p4v.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommended approach would be to do `p4 changes` on the source, run `p4 interchanges` between the source and target to get the source changes that have not been integrated, and diff the two to find the ones that have been integrated.

I'll also describe two other approaches that I would not recommend since they're a bit harder (but you might find elements of them useful):

- Run `p4 changes -i` on the target and then run lots of `p4 files` commands to filter it down to the changes that originated on the source.
- Run `p4 integrated -b branch`, run lots of `p4 changes` commands to convert the integration records into changelist ranges, and then sort them into a unified list.

Comment: A third idea: create a new branch, at the same initial branch point as this branch, but with no changes after that. Then run `p4 interchanges` from the base to the new branch, and compare that list to `p4 interchanges` from the base to this branch. Then discard this temporary branch.

Comment: These are kind of workarounds(not super elegant), I am talking about 1000s of files.

Comment: Yes, that's why I recommend the first option as the simplest (and fastest since it's only two commands plus a local diff).  With thousands of files the other two are doable but it'll probably take on the order of minutes (gated mostly by latency).

Comment: Yes, the 1st command is the fastest. The only issue is the branchspec, if multiple files have been renamed it is not that efficient, isnt it.

Comment: Shouldn't matter in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

Finding out if a changelist has been integrated into another branch in perforce is not simple. 'p4 interchanges' may not report everything as it relies on meta data and may 'think' that some changelists have been integrated.

Consider the case where CL10 was merged to branch B and then the changes were manually reverted via a 'p4 edit' instead of 'p4 undo' on B. Then if you run 'p4 integrate' with CL10 perforce returns with 'already integrated' message even though the code is no longer there (but might need to be).

Perhaps a solution to your question may involve combining ideas from Sam's answer above, 'p4 interchanges' and also running 'p4 integrate [-f]' within a loop to confirm that a set of changelists was indeed integrated. This is some work since the outputs of 'p4 resolve' and 'p4 diff/diff2' need to be considered.

My point is: do not solely rely on 'p4 interchanges'.